# Can I trace object identity using GetHashCode?

Tags: c#, identity, gethashcode

What is the use of `GetHashCode()`? Can I trace object identity using `GetHashCode()`? If so, could you provide an example?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hash codes aren't about identity, they're about equality. In fact, you could say they're about *non-equality*:

- If two objects have the same hash code, they *may* be equal
- If two objects have different hash codes, they're *not* equal

Hash codes are not unique, nor do they guarantee equality (two objects may have the same hash but still be unequal).

As for their uses: they're almost always used to quickly select *possibly equal* objects to then test for *actual* equality, usually in a key/value map (e.g. `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`) or a set (e.g. `HashSet<T>`).

Comment: Impeccable explanation Jon .Great.

Comment: HashCode is generated by the System ? like random number will it return random value ?

Comment: The default `GetHashCode` implementation returns some sort of internal object identifier used by the runtime. But since `GetHashCode` is virtual you can override it to return whatever you feel like. Check these two questions when you need to override it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873654/overriding-gethashcode-for-mutable-objects-c

Comment: Thank you for clearing my doubt.Thank you very much ,once again. :)

Answer (score 5):

No, a HashCode is not guaranteed to be unique. But you already have references to your objects, they are perfect for tracking identity, using [`object.ReferenceEquals()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: +1 Even though your wording is a little unclear your point is still there.

Comment: I think you should point that since `==` can be overloaded, so the correct way to test referential equality is the `object.ReferenceEquals()` method.

Comment: Thanks Martinho Fernandes to be specific

Comment: I went ahead and added it myself.

Answer (score 1):

The value itself is used in hashing algorithms, such as hashtables.

In its default implementation, GetHasCode does not guarantee the uniqueness of an object, thus for .NET objects should not be used as such,

In you own classes, it is generally good practice to override GetHashCode to create a unique value for your object.

Answer (score 1):

It's used for algorithms\data structures that require hashing (such as a hash table). A hash code cannot on its own be used to track object identity since two objects with the same hash are not necessarily equal. However, two equal objects should have the same hash code (which is why C# emits a warning if you override one without overriding the other).