# C# Looking for a key in a hash table and gather the corresponding value

Tags: c#, hashtable, point

can anyone tell me how I can search a hash table for a specific key and put off the corresponding value in a variable (e.g. Both key and value are from the class `point`)

I add the values as followed:

```
Hashtable Hash = new Hashtable();     
Hash.Add(new Point(Po.X - 1, Po.Y), new Point(Po.X, Po.Y));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
Point value;
if (Hash.ContainsKey(YourKey))
{
    value = (Point)Hash[YourKey];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `HashTable` you should look at generic [`Dictionary<T,T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx). *(if you are using .Net framework 2.0 or higher)*

But if you want to get the key from current non generic `HashTable` you can do:

```
var KeyToSearch = new Point(10 - 1, 20);
if (Hash.ContainsKey(KeyToSearch))
{
    var value = Hash[KeyToSearch];
}
```

But remember, `value` is of type `object`, and you have to use explicit cast to get `Point` object back like:

```
Point value = (Point) Hash[KeyToSearch] ;
```

If you were to use `Dictionary<Point,Point>`, then you can achieve the same thing without casting.

One more thing to add, `Point` here is considered a `struct` from `System.Drawing`, If it is a class then `ContainsKey` and accessing based on `Key` would compare the reference and not the actual values. If your `Point` is a class *(a reference type)* then you have to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` You may see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240467/overriding-gethashcode) for more details.